# Can't create process in pwntools

Tags: python, pwntools

I am trying to use python's pwntools. I want to start a process using

```
from pwn import *
s = process('./step1')
```

When I do this I receive the following error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pwnlib/tubes/process.py", line 267, in **init**
>       stdin, stdout, stderr, master, slave = self._handles(*handles)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pwnlib/tubes/process.py", line 603, in _handles
>       tty.setraw(master)
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tty.py", line 28, in setraw
>       tcsetattr(fd, when, mode)
>   termios.error: (22, 'Invalid argument')

I am already in the directory that contains the file step1 and step1 is executable. Does anyone have an idea why I get this error. If it helps, I am using the Linux subsystem on Windows 10.

Answer (score 8):

Check out [this link](http://docs.pwntools.com/en/stable/tubes/processes.html). `process()` needs its first argument as a list of program arguments. So

```
$ ./step1 arg1 arg2
```

is equivalent to

```
p = process(['step1', 'arg1', 'arg2'])
```